# Why Scala changed relative precedence of relational vs equality operators (compared to Java)?

Tags: scala

In Java, < has higher priority than ==. In Scala it's vice versa. I wonder why Scala people chose that way? Other binary operator precedences align with Java (exept bitwise ops, but it's understandable why they didn't give special precedences for those).

UPDATE: It was actually a mistake in the language spec, '<' has actually higher priority than '==' in Scala.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not inversed in Scala. Try this:

```
val what = 5 == 8 < 4
```

I get a compile-time warning: `` comparing values of types Boolean and Int using `==' will always yield false ``; so obviously the compiler has translated this to `5 == (8 < 4)`, just like in Java.

You can try this, too:

```
class Foo {
  def ===(o: Foo) = { println("==="); this }
  def <<<(o: Foo) = { println("<<<"); this }
  def >>>(o: Foo) = { println(">>>"); this }
}

def foo = new Foo
```

Then calling `foo === foo <<< foo >>> foo` prints this:

```
<<<
>>>
===
```

Which means it was parsed as `(foo === ((foo <<< foo) >>> foo))`

Can you provide an example where the precedence is reversed?

Comment: Then maybe it's a typo?… I wouldn't dare to contradict the Reference, but from these two tests, methods beginning with `<` have higher precedence than methods beginning with `=` when used in infix notation (on Scala 2.8.1).

Comment: Thanks for the extended example -- it really seems there is typo in the reference. I was comparing operator precedences in different languages, that's why I noticed it.

Comment: The documentation was still wrong in 2.8, where it claimed that infix operators starting with '=' are higher priority than those starting with '<', but it's not true. '5 < 4 == 5 < 4' works as expected, but 'true & false == true & false' is not the same as '(true & false) == (true & false)', even though '&' and '<' are both lower than '='.

Comment: Fixed at 2.11 (or earlier) - http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#prefix-operations